# Error in deployment to shinyapps.io

Tags: r, shiny

The following is the error i received:

```
Loading required package: tmap
Warning in library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
  there is no package called ‘tmap’
Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages(p) :
  'lib = "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library"' is not writable
Error in value[[3L]](cond) : unable to install packages
Calls: local ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted
```

The following is my code:

```
packages = c('tmap', 'sf', 'tidyverse', 'RColorBrewer', 'classInt', 
'raster', 'sp', 'REAT', 'SpatialAcc', 'shiny', 'leaflet', 'factoextra',  
'NbClust')

for(p in packages){
  if(!require(p, character.only = T)){
    install.packages(p)
  }
  library(p, character.only = T)
}
```

What could be the problem?.

I tried deploying through the following command in rstudio.

```
library(rsconnect)
rsconnect::deployApp('D:/student/mypath')
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that `shinyapps.io` doesn't let you install R packages on their server. Allowing that would not really make sense for security reasons so please don't try to "hack" your way into an installation.

Instead file an issue (or a PR) on the github repo [shinyapps dependencies](https://github.com/rstudio/shinyapps-package-dependencies/) and ask them to support your missing packages.

A second solution is to purchase a server and set up shiny-server yourself. Then you will be free to install packages at will. Instructions about that can be found [here](https://deanattali.com/2015/05/09/setup-rstudio-shiny-server-digital-ocean/).

---

**Edit**: Actually, it seems custom libraries are supported on `shinyapps.io` and they will be installed automatically based on your `library` and `require` calls. So you probably just need to remove the `ìnstall.packages` part in your uploaded app.

> When you deploy your application, the rsconnect package attempts to detect the packages that your application uses. rsconnect sends this list of packages and their dependencies along with your application to the shinyapps.io service. Then shinyapps.io builds and installs the packages into the R library for your application. The first time you deploy your application, it may take some time to build these packages (depending on how many packages are used). However, you will not wait for these packages to build during future deployments (unless you upgrade or downgrade a package)
>
> -- [Shinyapps.io - Getting started](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/shinyapps.html)