# Error on shiny website, but app works fine locally

Tags: r, shiny

I've been trying to resolve this issue for a while now and I can't seem to wrap my head around it. I've checked previous threads and they haven't helped, I'm guessing it's vastly different for each code, and I need some help understanding what I'm doing wrong here.

This is an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDw1t.png) of what the error looks like, I've used the Package::function method instead to access the masked functions so I don't think that's the issue.

Here's also a GitHub link: https://github.com/TheoLs/MHAnalysis to the shiny app, please don't go easy on me, I want to improve so tell me if there's something I'm doing wrong, even if it's not related to the issue, and I'll try and fix it.

Any help is welcome, and thank you in advance.

Comment: From the screenshot, error is clear `"Required package is missing"`

Comment: Like I said in the title, the exact same code works locally, so that's not the issue here. All the necessary packages are in.

Comment: GitHub link is broken.

Comment: Try to run an example shinyapp with all required packages on "shiny website" and see it fails due to missing packages again.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, fixed the link. And I did, the shiny app runs, but when running on the website it shows the error in the image.  https://theols.shinyapps.io/MH-Analysis/ Here is the shiny app website where I took the picture from.

Comment: Related post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49718846/680068

Comment: Apologies zx8754, you were right, I was missing a package, randomForest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the logs on shinyapps dashboard: [image: shinyapps.io] you will notice that the package randomforest, is missing:

```
2021-06-11T13:23:52.286950+00:00 shinyapps[4258238]: 1 package is needed for this model and is not installed. (randomForest). Would you like to try to install it now?Error in value[[3L]](cond) : Required package is missing.
```

Including `library(randomForest)` solves this issue. As far as I can tell, one of your packages relies on `randomForest` but its developer hasn't listed it as a required package in CRAN.

After adding randomForest, I ran into another problem, which was that the app takes over 60 seconds to load (naive_bayes takes a long time to run), and shinyapps.io times out after 60 secs.

You should separate model fitting and visualisation into separate programs to avoid running fitting and prediction online on shinyapps.

Comment: I can confirm, this is right. Looks like there was a package missing, after all, I apologize to @zx8754 he had mentioned this above too. I'm still new to shiny and didn't know about the logs tab there. I'll try and do as you suggested and split the app into 2, one for running the model fittings and the second one for the visualization, may as well do that for all of the models in the app.

Comment: Admittedly this is a bit obscure as an error because of the required/suggested issue I mention above. If you think that my answer solves your problem, could I ask you to approve?

Comment: Done! Apologies, I wasn't aware I had to do this.